# How to call direct parent element function

Tags: javascript, polymer

Please consider following example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.5.5/polymer.js"></script>
<polymer-element name="my-outer" >
  <template>
      outer
     <my-inner id="inner" >
         <button on-click="{{buttonClick}}">push</button>
     </my-inner>
      outer
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-outer', {
      buttonClick: function(){
          
          // it wasn't commented before update
          //this.$.inner.buttonClick();
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="my-inner">
  <template>
      <content></content>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-inner', {
      // update 
       domReady: function() {
        this.eventController = this;
       },
      //end update
      
       buttonClick: function(){
          alert('inner');
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<my-outer></my-outer>
```

The question is if there is any way to call Inner's buttonClick without explicit delegation in outer (putting $.inner... into on-click also doesn't work)? Maybe with bind or something.

Best reagrds, Eugene.

ps: the snippet works only in chrome. Not sure if it's polymer or stackoverflow to blame.

UPDATE: looks like putting

```
 domReady: function() {
        this.eventController = this;
 },
```

into inner component solves the problem. But I still don't fully undestand what that eventController is. When event handler is looking for one it just iterates through node parents and picks up any with defined eventController, if none is found then node.host is used. The only other place where eventController pops up in polymer code is some lightFromTemplate function with murky comment and TODO on it.Then there is also bug https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1170 and couple of posts which do not make the issue clear for me.

So the updated question is:
What is polymer's eventController and are there any ways to work with it?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using data-binding, but this solution is not elegant. I'd much more prefer your initial solution.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.5.5/polymer.js"></script>
<polymer-element name="my-outer">
  <template>
      outer
     <my-inner id="inner" clicked="{{clicked}}">
         <button on-tap="{{click}}">push</button>
     </my-inner>
      outer
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      clicked: false,
      click: function() {
        this.clicked = !this.clicked;
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="my-inner">
  <template>
      <content></content>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-inner', {
       publish: {
         clicked: {
           value: false,
           reflect: true
         }
       },
       clickedChanged: function() {
         alert('inner');
       }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<my-outer></my-outer>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! But as you said your solution doesn't look much better than original as it still makes same delegation but through events and thus outer elt needs to know too much about inners. In real life the outer elt is for layout and innter one to make ajax calls.

Comment: If you're really making such a strong distinction between your elements I don't believe it is possible what you are trying to achieve. That's because the shadow dom binds properties with a strict scope. Ofcourse I could be wrong but I just don't see any other way to achieve what you're trying to do

Comment: got it working - see updates, but not sure if it's a good way to go

Comment: I haven't heard of that property before. Glad you got it working though. I suggest you write a new answer to your original question explaining your solution and to ask about the eventController in a new question